# Amazon S3 image preview url

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a images storage in Amazon S3 and when I get images from it I get full sized images (each one is 5MB). Is it possible to get something like preview images (with less size), and if needed send request to normal image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 doesn't have this built in.  However, I could see a fairly simple [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) that would be called when an image is added to your S3 bucket.  It could store a thumbnail sized image in parallel with the full size image.

Your server would then have to know to show the thumbnail first and generate a link to the full sized image.  You'd also have to "bootstrap" the process once you installed the Lambda to take into account existing images.

Again, none of this is directly built into S3 but it wouldn't take too much to implement.

Comment: so as I've understood this work have to be done in backend?

Comment: The Lambda would be "serverless" in that you won't have a specific server running.  If you want this all to happen on the front end then you could certainly do that too - I'm not sure what your configuration looks like but your front end code should be able to just link to the thumbnail and/or the full res image.  But, again, you'd have to bootstrap the process to do the initial generation of the images.